# Could not identify a button for click in selenium test

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have this button

```
<button _ngcontent-gyx-c3="" class="btn btn-gradient-primary btn-icon-text p-3 col-12" routerlink="/certificate-request/create" routerlinkactive="active" type="button" tabindex="0"><i _ngcontent-gyx-c3="" class="icon-plus btn-icon-prepend"></i> New request </button>
```

how can i sleect it for seinuim test 
I tried this :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="btn btn-gradient-primary btn-icon-text p-3 col-12"][.="New request"]').click()
```

But I have the following exception:

> no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class="btn btn-gradient-primary btn-icon-text p-3 col-12"][.="New request"]"}
>     (Session info: headless chrome=72.0.3626.109)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple xpath patters that could work, this is one that's close to the one in your question.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="btn btn-gradient-primary btn-icon-text p-3 col-12"][text(),"New request"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to click on the element using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-gradient-primary.btn-icon-text[routerlink='/certificate-request/create'][routerlinkactive='active']>i.icon-plus.btn-icon-prepend"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@routerlink='/certificate-request/create' and @routerlinkactive='active']/i[@class='icon-plus btn-icon-prepend']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the option to put an id on your button and do it like this?

```
driver.find_element_by_id(<id_of_button>)
```

EDIT:

How about this?

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="icon-plus btn-icon-prepend"][.="New request"]').click()
```

Comment: I have no access to front code i just test it so i can not change any thing in source code

Comment: It does however look like the buttons are nested together in some way. I've edited my answer.